# JTable alignment of cell content in custom Renderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel, tablecellrenderer

I want to align the contents of the first column of my JTable to the center, but I can't get it to work. I got it to work if I set it without a custom Renderer but then it would overwrite the changes I'm trying to make for the row colors.

Eclipse tells me that the method setHorizontalAlignment is undefined for the type Component but that doesn't ring any bells with me. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
final TableCellRenderer renderer = table_1.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
    table_1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer()    {
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
      {
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        c.setBackground(row % 4 == 2 || row % 4 == 3 ? new Color(230,230,230) : Color.WHITE);
        c.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        return c;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and cast the variable c to JLabel:

```
JLabel c = (JLabel) renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(...);
```

The API for [DefaultTableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) will show you that this class in fact derives from JLabel which has the method that you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now. Now how could I apply the alignment only to the first column of my JTable but the colouring to the entire JTable? I can't use getColumnModel().getColumn(0) because JLabel does not support it as far as I can tell?

Comment: @cflx: look ***carefully*** at the parameter list of the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method. You should use one of the parameters and just a little bit of `if (...)` logic. I'll bet you can figure this out. ;)

Comment: @cflx: I knew you would.

Comment: Now I've run into another problem with the cell renderer: I'm trying to show an icon in a specific selection of cells, every second cell in the first column. My code looks like this:

if (column == 0 && row % 2 == 0) {c.setIcon(edit);}

But it now shows an icon in every cell of my table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got it: I had to c.setIcon(null); after casting the renderer on JLabel.